# AngularJS - do function in string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have in my page initialized this actions:

```
<div ng-click="unpublish()">unpublish</div>
<div ng-click="publish()">publish</div>
```

and I want do ng-click in action If I select option. I create:

```
<select ng-model="select" ng-change="selected()">
    <option value="publish()">Publish</option>
    <option value="unpublish()">Unpublish</option>
</select>
```

And in app.js in controller I have:

```
$scope.selected = function () {
        alert($scope.select); //this display correct selected value of option
        var callback = eval($scope.select);
        console.log(callback);
};
```

This code doesn't work, I want to do "$scope.select" - it's initialized in the same controller.

Comment: You should really avoid the use of `eval` also have you looked at `ng-options` for building your selects? You pass it an array of items, similar to `ng-repeat` and it allows you to build your selects very easily.

Comment: i don't think you can have function as value in option, the way you have written

Comment: I dont't use ng-options or ng-repeat, i write static DOM option value ...

How to do the same in similary DOM?

Comment: Store your functions in an object, and use their names as a values for options. Then you can call a function using bracket notation and a value. Notice also, that you've misused [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: If I use eval(); it will display that publish() is undefined

Comment: Please forget the eval, and read the documentation I've linked above. There's an example of how to not use eval in a similar case you have. Btw. `publish()` is not undefined in your code, `callback` is.